# Add class and remove class in Ul li a using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="tab_sublinks">
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Product Master</a></li>
    <li style="margin: 0;">|</li>
    <li><a href="#">Charges Computation Master</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to add `active` class in anchor tag when I click `<a>` and remove the `active` class from previous `<a>` tag

Comment: can you add a fiddle with your whole css and html code

Comment: Please share minimum piece of code what you have tried and also the markup!

Answer (score 4):

Try this one..

```
$(".tab_sublinks a").on("click", function(){
$(".tab_sublinks a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

this one will remove `active` class from all `a` tags inside `tab_sublinks` and add `active`  class to the current `element`.

Comment: I've already answered the same. Please check other answers before posting.

Comment: No issues buddy. I have updated my answer. :-) Also just a note, if possible, always try to explain your attempt. This will ensure everyone (*even beginners*) gets you answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a generic selector to remove `active` class from all `<a>` tags and then use `this` to add class to current tag.

#### Generic selector

This will work if the generic selector is unique i.e. you do not have more of `tab_sublinks`.

```js
$('.tab_sublinks a').on('click', function(){
  $(".tab_sublinks a").removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active{
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab_sublinks">
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Product Master</a></li>
    <li style="margin: 0;">|</li>
    <li><a href="#">Charges Computation Master</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### Search using this

This is more robust way as you are using `this` to search element and will have effect in current scope. If you have multiple `tab_sublinks` this is more preferred way

```js
$('.tab_sublinks a').on('click', function(){
  $(this)
  // Search nearest element with `tab_sublinks`
  .closest('.tab_sublinks')
  // Search for a.active in this element
  .find('li a.active').removeClass('active')
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active{
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab_sublinks">
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Product Master</a></li>
    <li style="margin: 0;">|</li>
    <li><a href="#">Charges Computation Master</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="tab_sublinks">
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Product Master</a></li>
    <li style="margin: 0;">|</li>
    <li><a href="#">Charges Computation Master</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the active class using the jQuery click event.

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {

  $('.js-nav-item').click(function() {
    $('.c-active-link').removeClass('c-active-link'); // Remove Class First
    $(this).addClass('c-active-link'); // Add Class to Active Item
  })

});
```

```css
.c-active-link {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab_sublinks">
  <li><a href="#" class="c-active-link js-nav-item">Product Master</a>
  </li>
  <li style="margin: 0;">|</li>
  <li><a href="#" class="js-nav-item">Charges Computation Master</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This will have huge impact as `.active` can be applied to a lot of elements

Comment: @Rajesh you are correct if OP was using the class `active` in multiple areas. However, this will not impact the user if the class is unique to the nav area (i.e. `c-active-link`) but OP is asking for jQuery advice and not performance/structural advice.

Comment: `.active` is a very commonly and widely used class. But yes, if OP is using only one element, nothing wrong with it

Comment: I have updated my answer to portray the uniqueness of the nav-link active class. Whatever OP is planning to develop I am certain they will intend on avoiding css/jQuery conflicts in their code.